# Jasmine spy naming

Tags: javascript, mocking, jasmine

When creating spies in [Jasmine](http://jasmine.github.io/edge/introduction.html) tests, spy names must be passed, e.g.:

```
var spy = jasmine.createSpy('spy');
...
expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

1. What is the purpose of those names?
2. Are there any constraints on naming spies, e.g. global uniqueness?
3. Such names seem to me redundant. Is it possible to avoid specifying them in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lets do a simple experiment (tested on Jasmine 2.0):

```
it("sandbox playground", function() {
    var twin1 = jasmine.createSpy('twin brother').and.returnValue({});
    var twin2 = jasmine.createSpy('twin brother').and.returnValue({});
    var unnamed = jasmine.createSpy(undefined).and.returnValue({});
    var skipped = jasmine.createSpy().and.returnValue({});
    expect(twin1).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(twin2).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(unnamed).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(skipped).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

Results:

```
Firefox 56.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) Sample Tests. sandbox playground FAILED
    Expected spy twin brother to have been called.
    @tests/sampleTests.spec.js:37:9
    Expected spy twin brother to have been called.
    @tests/sampleTests.spec.js:38:9
    Expected spy unknown to have been called.
    @tests/sampleTests.spec.js:39:9
    Expected spy unknown to have been called.
    @tests/sampleTests.spec.js:40:9
```

So, to answer your questions:

1. It is for meaningful message when some assertions fail.
2. As we can see, the framework itself doesn't check them, so formally there aren't any.

   But anyway I would suggest to introduce some conventions for
   yourself to have readable and meaningful test results to minimize
   effort of debugging failed test cases.
3. As we can see, it is possible. But as mentioned, I would suggest not to do it.